# Sistema de busca com codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, algoritmo-de-busca

será que alguém poderia me indicar um bom tutorial, ou uma forma de se fazer um sistema de busca com o codeigniter? Desde já agradeço.

Comment: obrigado pela opinião, sou novo por aqui, muito obrigado, mas esta parte foi concluida, agradeço.

Answer (score 2):

É bem simples

```
  $busca = $this->input->post('busca'); 

  $query_busca = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE coluna LIKE '%".$busca."%' ")->result();


  $data=[
        "resultados" => $query_busca,
 ias
          ];

     $data_content = array(
        'content' => $this->load->view('pasta/pagina', $data, true)
    );


    }
}
```